# echoing a result from a codeIgniter function needs jquery

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when echoing an array from a mysql query, console sends me an error that it needs jquery.

my problem originally was how to output the one query result from an array. I found a solution where using $arrayName[index][index] should do it but when I tried it the browser console shows an POST http://localhost:8080/logInCon/validate_LogIn 500 (Internal Server Error)

this is the query function

```
Model:
public function logInCheck($uname, $psswrd)
    {
        $log = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'verified' FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname' AND `pwd` = '$psswrd' LIMIT 1;");
        return $log->result();
    }
```

this is results
Controller:

```
public function validate_LogIn()
    {
        $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
        $this->load->model("accsModel");
        $data = $this->accsModel->logInCheck($uname, $pass);

        echo $data[0]['verified'];
    }
```

I want to get that one value inside $data

Comment: you can echo array with `echo json_encode($data) `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can echo simply this way.**

*A better way to use active record*

*Model function / query*

```
public function logInCheck($uname, $psswrd)
    {
        $this->db->select('COUNT(*) AS verified');
        $this->db->where('uname', $uname);
        $this->db->where('pwd', $psswrd);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        return $this->db->get('users')->row_array();
    }
```

*Result / used function*

```
public function validate_LogIn()
    {
        $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
        $this->load->model("accsModel");
        $data = $this->accsModel->logInCheck($uname, $pass);

        echo $data['verified'];
    }
```

Comment: oh thanks. didn't know I can do this way. looks cleaner and easier to look at.. Thanks for the help. and I'll read about more on the row_array() function.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use row();
Model:

```
public function logInCheck($uname, $psswrd)
    {
        $log = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'verified' FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname' AND `pwd` = '$psswrd' LIMIT 1;");
        return $log->row('verified');//changes
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function validate_LogIn()
    {
        $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
        $pass = $this->input->post('pass');
        $this->load->model("accsModel");
        $data = $this->accsModel->logInCheck($uname, $pass);

        echo $data;die;
    }
```